# Python 3.6.2 - Trying to install pip through cmd, get the following TypeError:

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, path, pip

- I'm trying to install kivy, but my computer doesn't recognise me as having installed pip so I run get-pip.py through my cmd and this is what happens:
- When I type: cd \Users\jmcco\Desktop\python-3.6.2-embed-amd64\ and then type: python get-pip.py I get an error message that reads: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

The whole cmd output reads:

File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in 
    main()

File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)

File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip

File "", line 961, in _find_and_load

File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked

File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible

File "C:\Users\jmcco\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8xsq68ol\pip.zip\pip__init__.py", line 26, in

File "", line 961, in _find_and_load

File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked

File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible

File "C:\Users\jmcco\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8xsq68ol\pip.zip\pip\utils__init__.py", line 23, in

File "", line 961, in _find_and_load

File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked

File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible

File "C:\Users\jmcco\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8xsq68ol\pip.zip\pip\locations.py", line 88, in

File "ntpath.py", line 75, in join

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

C:\Users\jmcco\Desktop\python-3.6.2-embed-amd64>

Comment: What does `python get-pip.py` from a command line do?

Answer (score 0):

So, if Windows doesn't recognize something as a script (for example, if you're using `.py` extension), then it will try to open the file in whatever it has as a default editor. In your case, it's Atom. In my case (when I used Windows) it was Notepad++.

Regardless, you need to use the command prompt to get this working:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> A prompt will show up.
- Type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> in the prompt.
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd> This will drop you into the command prompt.
- Type `python` then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> If you have an error, then you don't have Python.
- Paste/type `cd \Users\jmcco\Desktop\python-3.6.2-embed-amd64\`
- Type `python get-pip.py`

Alternatively, you could use Anaconda, which should allow you to use a GUI to install.

Comment: This definitely did something different, however I got at the end this line: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType". I checked my pathways and there are no changes.

Comment: I ended up just uninstalling my zipped version of Python and installed the executable version which has pip already on it.